# Can't get code to execute at certain time

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to get some code to execute at a certain time but I can't figure out what the problem is here. Please help?

```
import datetime
dt=datetime
set_time=dt.time(12,53)
timenow=dt.datetime.now()
time=False
while not time:
 if timenow==set_time:
    print("yeeehaaa")
    time=True
    break
else:
    print("naaaaa")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you have to update the time inside the loop or it will always be comparing the same `timenow` to `set_time`, then convert all to just an hour/minute string and compare

```
import datetime
dt=datetime
set_time=str(dt.time(14,19))[0:5]
timenow=dt.datetime.now().time()
time=False
while not time:
 timenow=str(dt.datetime.now().time())[0:5]
# print(timenow)
 if timenow==set_time:
    print("yeeehaaa")
    time=True
    break
else:
    print("naaaaa")
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I also tried the following for setting the time but this did not work, can you see a problem?     set_time=datetime.datetime(year=2022, month=12, day=1, hour=13, minute=54, second=0, microsecond=0, tzinfo=None, fold=0)

Comment: it is working.. the output of `print(set_time)` is `2022-12-01 13:54:00`. If you want the code to run at ay certain time and certain hour you have to do more modifications

Comment: Did you see in my comment above how i have tried to change set_time?  It does not work like this...  set_time=datetime.datetime(year=2022, month=12, day=1, hour=13, minute=54, second=0, microsecond=0, tzinfo=None, fold=0)

Comment: again if the function that you wan t to use to set time is datetime.datetime you have to change a lot of thing in the code, so either edit your question or just ask a new one, becouse the approach will be very different

Answer (score 0):

Changing your code to something like this should solve your issue:

```
import datetime.datetime as dt
set_time=dt.time(12,53)

# the loop waits for the time condition to be met.
# we use the lower than condition in order not to miss the time
# by a few fraction of second.
while (dt.now() < set_time):
    time.sleep(0.1) # 100ms delay

# reaching there implies the time condition is met!
print("it is time!")
```

However there is a much simpler alternative which would consists in get the time delta between the current time and the target time in order to make one single wait with `time.sleep(time_delta_s)`.